# Accessing class attributes and class properties in a uniform way

Tags: python, properties

When reading an instance attribute it does not matter if it is a regular attribute or a property.

However with class attributes (shared by all instances) I have to distinguish those two types:

```
class Prop:
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return "VALUE"

class CP: 
    value = Prop()
    other = "OTHER"

print(CP.value.__get__(CP))
print(CP.other)
```

I need to lookup the values by name, I guess I will need something like:

```
v = getattr(CP, attrname)
if hasattr(v, '__get__'):
    return v.__get__(CP)
return v
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You want to get the attributes which are descriptors by name?

Comment: @Vinny Yes. I need property to implement data persistence and acces by name for an API function `get_value(name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `property` decorator is used in the class definition and accessed on the instance. So if you want a property on a class you need to use the `property` in the metaclass and then you can access the value on the class itself.

```
>>> class TypeWithValue(type):
    @property
    def value(cls):
        return "VALUE"


>>> class CP(metaclass=TypeWithValue):
    pass

>>> CP.value
'VALUE'
```

However, note that unlike an ordinary class variable which may be accessed either through a reference to the class or a reference to the instance this metaclass property can only be used directly on the class:

```
>>> CP().value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    CP().value
AttributeError: 'CP' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Every object in python is an instance of some type (for user defined types this is usually a `class`). Classes themselves are instances of a type, usually that is the type called `type` but you can use a subclass of `type` instead to apply your own behaviour that works in the instance of the type, i.e. on a class.